# Locked out of our Comcast Business Gateway for seemingly no reason

Tags: router

Last fall we migrated our ISP from AT&T to Comcast at one of our offices. At that time, we received a new modem/router from Comcast and we configured everything to our liking. We've never really had very many issues with the router aside from having to restart it every once in a while.

About three months ago I changed the password on the router from the default. After that, I logged into the router several times to make changes with no issue. During May I logged into the router to add two new static routes, no problems. A week ago, I tried to log into the router and could not. I tried the non-default password that I changed it to, the default, anything and everything I could think of and no luck. I restarted the router on Monday thinking it may just be locked up, but after the restart it would still not let me log in.

This router is at our other office about 2 hours from here and I want to avoid having to drive down there and reset to factory defaults, reconfigure, etc…

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you call Comcast?

Comment: Were you the only person with the password...?

Comment: No, I sent out an e-mail to our administrators at that time.  And documented the change.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest things that don't occur to you...

Doug, thank you very much!  I was able to call Comcast and have them reset the router password remotely.

Comment: Um...that's still not a good thing, necessarily. *WHO RESET IT?*

Comment: Did another admin do it? Was Comcast doing something?...this is like discovering someone is leaving things around your house and you just shrug your shoulders, throw the items out every day, and ignore that a stranger is *getting into your house.* You might want to investigate this.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming this was an SMC-branded Comcast cable modem, the usual `cusadmin:highspeed` username:password combination should work.

However, a safer long-term solution would be to use the Comcast-provided modem in "bridge mode" and install a proper router behind it. This will allow you to make the types of firewall rule and route changes you need without disrupting the cable modem's configuration. I've also seen the Comcast business class modems lose their configurations or get stuck in a strange state. I've replaced one unit at a client location *eight* times in two years.

Edit:

Comcast have also pushed out firmware that requires you to call them to reset the password to the `cusadmin:highspeed` combination listed above. This has played itself out on the [Comcast Business Support Forums...](http://forums.businesshelp.comcast.com/t5/Equipment-Modems-Gateways/Router-cable-password-changed-on-me/td-p/255/page/14) - Sad.

Comment: I believe that we will be going this route in the near future.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Is that cable modem even _capable_ of bridge mode? I could never find any such option.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That model is... Newer models require you to call Comcast and have a tech enable bridge mode remotely. It's no longer a user-accessible feature.

Comment: Years later, and the situation is even worse.  You apparently can't use Comcast equipment in bridge mode if you want to use static IPs due to how Comcast routes static IPs using the modem as a gateway.  So we're stuck paying for consumer-grade equipment as a relay if you want static IPs at all.  Ironically, if you are a home user with a dynamic IP you can just buy your own modem (non-gateway) and then use your own routing equipment.  It's beyond ridiculous.

Comment: I haven’t had this problem with recent Comcast Business installations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will address the issue presented but perhaps?

Comcast has some settings that they do not allow their Business Class customers access to.

My setup has a Cisco router behind the Comcast SMC8014 device.  Their default settings: To login to the Comcast I have to be in the "DMZ" subnet (192.168.x.x) between the Comcast and my Cisco.  Comcast can change a setting that allows me to connect through my Cisco from my internal subnet (172.23.x.x)  If I attempt to login from my internal subnet I get the login screen but it tells me I have an "Incorrect login"" I have four offices and it has been like pulling their tech support persons tooth to get them to change this setting.  They tell me that it is against Comcast policy.

The last time I had some problems at a remote site and Comcast "worked" on that modem they reset this setting and now I cannot connect from my office.  (I have not yet asked them to fix this)

This setting will also allow direct access to the Comcast device from the internet.  So if you can get them to allow this it is imperative that you have a very complex and secure password.  (Since Comcast also will not allow us to change the User name, it gives a hacker a great advantage trying to break into your system.)  Why they have a problem with this I have no clue.  If this was a Consumer product OK.  But it seems that Business Class is not designed for Businesses that have professional IT departments.